# Переадресация в htaccess если вводится..../feed , а не /feed/

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Доброго времени суток

В htaccess есть такая конструкция:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^feed/$ wp-content/cache/supercache/testsite\.ru/feed/
</IfModule>
```

Как её поправить, чтобы в случае ввода `testsite.ru/feed` переадресовывалось на `testsite.ru/feed/` и соответственно открывалось требуемое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для всех Url:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Только для /feed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /feed
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Премного благодарен! Работает :-)